# Mathematica Kernels and CPU cores

Tags: kernel

I want to use an 8 kernel Mathematica 12.2 version. Does a core i7 CPU with 4 cores and 4 threads fully utilize the benefit of the 8 kernels or an 8-core CPU is needed?

Comment: This will depend strongly on the workload. Generally, one physical core is recommended per thread for optimal performance gains (any more threads will give diminishing returns in many circumstances). However, a single Mathematica kernel might be able to use multiple cores thanks to automatic threading.